# Qt: Multiple dynamic plots

Tags: c++, qt

If I need to have multiple dynamic plots, updated at 2Hz, 500 of them.
What would be the best solution to keep the GUI thread away from blocking?

Answer (score -1):

Render to bitmap (`QPixmap`) in a background thread, pass bitmap to `QPainter::drawPixmap` on main thread. It doesn't matter too much if the latter part takes 1 ms per bitmap: you'd still only have 25% CPU use for the main thread, and "blocking" for 1 ms at a time isn't noticeable.

[edit]
Apparently this only works in Qt for Windows. You can still render to a C++ 2D array (`std::array` or `std::vector`) if you're doing the drawing manually.

Comment: But isn't QPixmap supposed to be used in only the GUI thread? Or you mean use the QImage?

Comment: You cannot render to `QPixmap` from a thread that is not the GUI thread.

Comment: @alediaferia: Source? Neither the QPixmap documentation nor the [overall note on thread safety](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-reentrancy.html) claims this.

Comment: https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/57756e72adf2081137b97f0e689dd16c770d10b1:src/gui/image/qpixmap.cpp#L103

Comment: Too bad it isn't documented though. But I've always experienced this with Qt, and the sources say it all. IIRC there's a bug report open to ask for supporting non-GUI threads with QPixmap but that's hardly feasible on non-Windows platforms.